# How to convert a json file into a list

Tags: python, json

**The content of my json file is:**

```
{'user': 'fgb59h', 'stars': 4.0, 'time': 1027296000}

{'user': 'bucho_ky', 'stars': 2.0, 'time': 1201305600}

{'user': 'redp944', 'stars': 4.0, 'time': 1118016000}
```

**And I want to convert it like this:**

```
[
{"user": "fgb59h", "stars": 4.0, "time": 1027296000}

{"user": "bucho_ky", "stars": 2.0, "time": 1201305600}

{"user": "redp944", "stars": 4.0, "time": 1118016000}
]
```

**I converted the single quotes to double quotes like this:**

```
with open('ep.json', 'r') as myfile:
    data=myfile.read()
obj = json.dumps(data)
json_ep = obj.replace("'", "\"")
```

But now i need the json file to be included in a list. Is there any way to do this?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: That is not valid JSON, as you *must* use double-quotes for JSON. Also, a flat collection of objects not in a list or another object is not valid either.

Comment: Are you trying to write JSON to a file for some other process to use, or just read the data into a list of dictionaries in memory in Python?

Comment: `dumps` takes a Python value and *produces* JSON. You want `loads`, which takes a JSON value and produces a Python value.

Comment: As it *appears* your input file contains a single JSON object per line, you'll have to read the file line by line and pass each line to `json.loads`.

Comment: Missing `,` in your json perhaps?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "*need the json file to be included in a list*"? Do you want to serialize all objects as "list" to a JSON file?

Comment: Christina, were you able to solve this?

Comment: @DirtyBit No, I wasn't able to solve it because there is an error in this line `print(json.dumps([ast.literal_eval(i) for i in res], indent = 4))` _SyntaxError: invalid syntax_

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: @DirtyBit Finally I solved it! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could read each line, append to a list which later can be manipulated using `ast`:

commitJson.json:

```
{'user': 'fgb59h', 'stars': 4.0, 'time': 1027296000}
{'user': 'bucho_ky', 'stars': 2.0, 'time': 1201305600}
{'user': 'redp944', 'stars': 4.0, 'time': 1118016000}
```

**Hence**:

```
import json
import ast
res = []
with open('commitJson.json', 'r') as fp:
    for line in fp:
        res.append(line.strip())

print(json.dumps([ast.literal_eval(i) for i in res], indent = 4))
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
[
    {
        "user": "fgb59h",
        "stars": 4.0,
        "time": 1027296000
    },
    {
        "user": "bucho_ky",
        "stars": 2.0,
        "time": 1201305600
    },
    {
        "user": "redp944",
        "stars": 4.0,
        "time": 1118016000
    }
]
```

**Shorter-version**:

```
with open('commitJson.json', 'r') as fp:
     print(json.dumps([ast.literal_eval(line.strip()) for line in fp], indent = 4))
```

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to load this file out of the box with `json`. You'll have to replace all single qutores first and then load the data with `json.loads`. However, you can also use `ast` in order to read the single-quoted json as follows:

```
import ast
from io import StringIO

data = """
{'user': 'fgb59h', 'stars': 4.0, 'time': 1027296000}

{'user': 'bucho_ky', 'stars': 2.0, 'time': 1201305600}

{'user': 'redp944', 'stars': 4.0, 'time': 1118016000}
"""

records = list()
for line in StringIO(data).readlines():
    if not len(line.strip()): continue
    data_dict = ast.literal_eval(line)
    records.append(data_dict)

print(records)
```

Which outputs:

```
[{'stars': 4.0, 'time': 1027296000, 'user': 'fgb59h'},
 {'stars': 2.0, 'time': 1201305600, 'user': 'bucho_ky'},
 {'stars': 4.0, 'time': 1118016000, 'user': 'redp944'}]
```

Comment: Not the output OP wanted.

Comment: @DirtyBit True, I was a bit confused about that "*need the json file to be included in a list*" part - asking OP ..

Comment: `ast.literal_eval` is certainly a reasonable approach for parsing strings that you're certain are valid Python literals. Take care, though, around JSON objects that aren't also valid Python -- in particular, `true`, `false`, and `null`. None of these appear in the OP's input, so maybe those values are not something to be concerned about in this particular problem.